# Ajax post cross domain request to instagram

Tags: ajax, post, instagram, http-delete

I am trying to make request to delete comment via Instagram API. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" + mediaId + "/comments/" + commentId + "?access_token=" + accessToken,
    data: { _method: "DELETE" },
    success: function(result){
        ...
    }
});
```

But I get this two errors:

1. > No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://timetoplay.alexjcomp.lclients.ru' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
2. > Status Code:400 BAD REQUEST

First is from console and second from network tab in chrome.
As I understand my problem is that I can not make CORS Post request. With CORS GET request everything was just fine because I used `dataType: "jsonp"`. How can I fix it in this case?

Comment: A 400 means the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. In other words, the URL is wrong.

Comment: Why are you trying to use POST when you're trying to delete??

Comment: did you find a solution for delete instagram likes? i have same problem

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for how to delete an Instagram comment:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#delete_media_comments

And I didn't test this code but I would assume all you need is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" + mediaId + "/comments/" + commentId + "?access_token=" + accessToken,
    success: function(result){
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Jim instagram docs are [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#)
I noted that you are also passing commentId which is not needed , just mention the media id like this

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

your ajax should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" + mediaId + "/comments/?access_token=" + accessToken,
        success: function(result){
            ...
        }
    });
```

I haven't tested it but you can give it a try.Hope it helps.